# I'm implementing a marquee effect but its not working on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm implementing a marquee effect but its not working on Android Studio.
This is the code
**This is the .xml file part for the textview:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/logos"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TRAVEL PORTAL"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="62dp" />
```

**This is my main_activity code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView logos = findViewById(R.id.logos);
        logos.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
        logos.setSelected(true);
}
```

Comment: Your text seems very short. Have you tried with longer texts?

Comment: So it has to be a long text for it to work?

Comment: Yes when the text becomes more than the width of the textview

Comment: Thank you! That helped and made sense.